# What part # will allow me to add neutral lug for subpanel?

Tags: electrical-panel, neutral

I am adding a 150A subpanel (Both panels are Square D Homeline), and I cannot find the part to add a neutral lug to attach the wire to the main panel's neutral. I believe that the best place to connect the neutral is the part pictured below. However, the square hole is obviously not threaded, so I'm not sure how it would connect. I could just screw a lug into the top threaded hole of the bus. What is the best approach here, and what Square D part do I need?

[image: bracket at top-left of neutral bus]

Comment: Picture of the full panel, picture of the labeling, model # (if it isn't clear on the label), size (A) of feed to the main panel.

Comment: Can you post a photo of the label on the inside of your loadcenter cabinet please? (It should be on either the left or right side)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your panel model and buss rating, you'll want either the LK150AN or LK225AN (in case it isn't obvious, the model number for the panel and for the accessories contain the panel buss amperage rating).

FWIW, depending on the rating, the aux lug will likely straddle the neutral bar, covering a couple screw holes.  I don't believe there are field-installable parts that fit that square hole although the ones I have in my bag are only 125A rated - I haven't ever installed one of the bigger ones.

[image]

Here's a link to the product page on Square D's website for the LK150AN:  [Product Information: LK150AN](https://www.se.com/us/en/product/LK150AN/load-center-accessory-qo-homeline-lug-kit-neutral-150a-awg-23-0-aluminum-or-copper/?range=7249-qo-load-centers)